# gridview with 4 textboxes in a row in VB.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview with 4 textboxes in a row.User enters text in first Textbox in first row. Other textboxes are read-only and have their value auto-flilled based on value of first Textbox. When I press 'enter' or 'tab' key, textbox focus should go to first textbox of second row. How can I achieve this?.Tab index doesnt seem to be working. I'm doing it in VB.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `RoWDataBound` event:-

**Update:**

Declare a Page level variable to hold the TabIndex:-

```
Dim index As Short = 0
```

RowDataBoundEvent:-

```
Protected Sub grdCustomer_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        index += 1
        Dim txtID As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtID"), TextBox)
        txtID.TabIndex = index
        //Other TextBox(s)
        Dim txtName As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtName"), TextBox)
        Dim txtCity As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtCity "), TextBox)
       txtName.TabIndex = txtCity.TabIndex = -1 //Set TabIndex of Readonly textbox to -1
    End If
End Sub
```

Here `txtID` will be the textbox id of your first textbox in each row, and set other textbox TabIndex to `-1` so that they will never be focused.

TextBox Change Event:-

```
Protected Sub txtID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim txtID As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
   //Logic to populate other textbox.

   Dim focusIndex As Short = CShort(txtID.TabIndex + 1)
   Dim tabbedRow = grdCustomer.Rows.OfType(Of GridViewRow) _
                              .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) (CType(x.FindControl("txtID"), TextBox)).TabIndex = focusIndex)
   If tabbedRow IsNot Nothing Then
        tabbedRow.FindControl("txtID").Focus()
   End If
End Sub
```

**Logic:**

Since we have set the `TabIndex` of first textbox in each row in order, in textChanged event I am finding the textbox with TabIndex equal to current textbox tabIndex + 1 and setting the focus on that textbox.